# How can I hide event log in IntellijIdea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I was unable to find an option allowing to do this. Note that I know how can I hide event log window, I want to hide also its summary form (text on the status bar with icon allowing to bring event log window back).

Ability to filter messages also would solve this problem.

[image: a busy cat]

I marked parts of interface that I want to remove.

It is distracting and in my experience it never has an important information.

Even the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/event-log.html) has

> shows the information about "important" events

(scare quotes are present in original).

Answer (score 5):

You can toggle event log window from menu - `View->Tool Windows->Event Log`.

Or, you can also hide it by clicking on the icon on the top-right of the Event Log window. The icon looks like a bar (half black and half white) with an arrow facing downward.

If you don't want anything on the `Event Log Window`, go to `Prefrences` and disable `Notifications`. Event Log Window displays notifications so you can disable notification and nothing will be logged.

Comment: It hides window, but event log is still displayed at the bottom with spam like "Plugin '.gitignore .hgignore .npmignore .dockerignore support' was successfully installed(...)".

Comment: Seems you don't want anything to be logged. Edited the answer :-)

Comment: It fixed one of my problems (some authors continuously update plugins, on every update there is a pop-up asking for donations) - but problem that I am trying to describe here is still present. I added image to my question showing what goes wrong.

Comment: Did you try marking all events as 'read'? Or did you restart the IDE after disabling notification ? I guess the notifications already in event log will remain there unless you delete them or mark them as 'read'. Disabling notification will stop future event log but the current one will still be there.

Comment: It removes icon, but text in status bar is still present (for example information that I made commit using Intellij Idea GUI).

Comment: In case of interest, I just checked to see if there is a file on disk containing this event log content (wanted to grep it for the build times, actually) but there is no file containing the notifications of the build time, as seen in the event log window (e.g. "Build completed successfully with 1,750 warnings in 5 min, 20 sec").

Comment: Although not the main point, you can also hide the window by typing `Shift + Esc` as keyboard shortcut.